# VBscript Replace text with part of filename

Tags: vbscript

I have a directory of files that I want to Loop through and use part of their filename to replace text in a template doc.

For example one filename may be 'NV_AD32_city.dxf'.  All files in the directory follow the same filename pattern of XX_XXXX_string.dxf, using two underscores.

I need to capture the string to the right of the first "_" and to the left of the "."so for this example that would be 'AD32_city'

How do I script to use capture that text of the active file to replace text in the template?  I guess I need to create an object?  But what is the object to use for the current file from a directory?
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Thx for the replies, guys.  After several days of trying your code I am just not "getting it".  I understand it is set up to take the part of the filename's string that I want but how do I tell the script to use the current file I am looping through?  Here is my script so far. I have your code on line 20 under the Sub 'GetNewInputs'

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Option Explicit
Dim WritePath : WritePath = "S:\TempFolder\"
Dim OutFile : OutFile = "VEG_DXF-2-SHP_script-"
Dim WorkingFile : WorkingFile = GetFileContent(SelectFile())
Dim NewState, NewSection, NewArea
Dim OldState, OldSection, OldArea

Call GetNewInputs()
Call GetOldInputs()

Sub GetNewInputs()       
        NewState = UCase(InputBox("INPUT STATE:", _
        "INPUT STATE", "SOCAL"))

        NewSection = ("Section_" & InputBox("INPUT SECTION NUMBER:", _
        "INPUT SECTION", "14"))

        NewArea = "^[^_]+_(.*)\.dxf$"       
End Sub

Private Sub GetOldInputs()
        OldState = "XX"
        OldSection = "_X"
        OldArea = "ZZZZ"   
End Sub

Function SelectFile()  
        SelectFile = vbNullString  
        Dim objShell : Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  
        Dim strMSHTA : strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input        type=file id=FILE>" _  
        &"<" & "script>FILE.click();new     ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _  
       &".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & "/script>"""  

    SelectFile = objShell.Exec(strMSHTA).StdOut.ReadLine()  

    If SelectFile = vbNullString Then  
            WScript.Echo "No file selected or not a text file."  
            WScript.Quit  
    End If  
End Function

Private Function GetFileContent(filePath)      
    Dim objFS, objFile, objTS      
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")      
    Set objFile = objFS.GetFile(filePath)      
    Set objTS = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(1, 0)      

    GetFileContent = objTS.Read(objFile.Size)      
    Set objTS = Nothing      
End Function

For Each FileRefIn fso.GetFolder("S:\SOCAL\Section_14\Veg DXFs\").Files
    NewFile = WorkingFile
    NewFile = Replace(NewFile, OldState, NewState)
    NewFile = Replace(NewFile, OldSection, NewSection)
    NewFile = Replace(NewFile, OldArea, NewArea)
    WriteFile NewFile, WritePath & OutFile & ".gms"
    WScript.Echo NewArea
Next

Private Sub WriteFile(strLine,fileName)  
    On Error Resume Next  
    Dim objFSO, objFile  
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  

    Do Until IsObject(objFile)  
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fileName, 8, True)  
    Loop  

    objFile.WriteLine strLine  
    objFile.Close  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that’s actually two questions.

To enumerate files in a directory, you can use FileSystemObject, like this (untested)

```
const strFolderPath = "C:\Temp\Whatever"
set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder( strFolderPath )
set colFiles = objFolder.Files
for each objFile in colFiles
    ' Do whatever you want with objFile
next
```

[Here's the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bkx696eh(v=vs.84).aspx) of those objects properties/methods.

And to extract portion of file names, you could use a regular expression.

[Here’s some guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) how to use'em in VBScript.

The following expression should work for you, it will capture the portion of that file names you asked for:

`"^[^_]+_(.*)\.dxf$"`

Comment: Thx for the replies, guys.  After several days of trying your code I am just not "getting it".  I understand it is set up to take the part of the filename's string that I want but how do I tell the script to take the from the current file I am looping through?  Here is my script so far:

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit the content of the .dxf files, you will need to work within the AutoCAD VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) environment.

If that is the case, you will need to start with something like below:

```
GetObject("AutoCAD.Application.20")
CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application.20")
```

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-0225808C-8C91-407B-990C-15AB966FFFA8-htm.html

** Please take note that "VBA is no longer distributed with the AutoCAD installation; it must be downloaded and installed separately. The VBA Enabler for Autodesk AutoCAD can be downloaded [here](http://www.autodesk.com/vba-download)."